# Finding a red ace before black ace in a deck

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

We draw cards one by one from a deck.If for the first time we see a red ace at position 6, what is the probability after that to see a red ace before black ace?.

What I have tried is the following - Let $A$ be the event of finding a red ace at position 6 and let B be the event : there is a red ace at position >6 and less than the position of the last black ace .

so we have to find : $P(B|A) = P(BA)P(A) = P(B \cap A)P(A) $.

P(A) is $\frac{46}{{52}\choose{2}}$ , because for the denominator the 2 aces can be anywhere in the 52 cards , and for the numerator if the first is at position 6 then we have the second red ace to be from positions [7;52] which is ${46}\choose{1}$ which is 46.

But how can I compute $P(BA)$ ?

Comment: Is position 6 is the first time we see a *red ace*, or the first time we see an *ace* (whether red or black?)

Comment: position 6 is the first time we see a red ace!

Comment: Too bad .... :)

Comment: If the two black aces were in the first 6 cards, can you still see the 'second red ace before the black ace'?  That is, do you need to see the black ace after the second red ace ... or is it enough for the next ace to be red?

Comment: ok, so split it into 3 cases: Case 1: None of the first 5 cards were Black aces. Case 2: exactly 1 of the first 5 cards were Black aces. Case 3: exactly 2 of the first five cards were Black aces. That covers all possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it too complicated with the $46$ remaining cards. Just consider this:  If in the first $5$ cards there were no black aces, then there are three aces (two blacvk and one red) remaining in the $46$ cards, and since each is equally likely to show up next, the probability of the next ace being red is $\frac{1}{3}$

Likewise, if one of the first five cards was a black ace, then the probability of the first case after the first red ace being red is $\frac{1}{2}$

And if both black aces were among the first $5$ cards, then the probabilitt of the next ace being red is $1$.

Now, the probability of not getting any black aces in the first $5$ cards, given that the first red ace is in position $6$ is the probability of not getting aces at all in the first $5$ cards, and that is

$$\frac{{48 \choose 5}}{{52 \choose 5}}$$

The probability of getting $1$ black ace in the first $5$ cards and not getting any red aces is

$$\frac{{2 \choose 1}\cdot {48 \choose 4}}{{52 \choose 5}}$$

And the probability of getting both black aces but no red aces is:

$$\frac{{2 \choose 2}\cdot {48 \choose 3}}{{52 \choose 5}}$$

So, the probability is:

$$\frac{{48 \choose 5}}{{52 \choose 5}}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{{2 \choose 1}\cdot {48 \choose 4}}{{52 \choose 5}}\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{{2 \choose 2}\cdot {48 \choose 3}}{{52 \choose 5}} \cdot 1$$